# How do I convert an image into vector path and then get the coordinates?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, vector, export

I am new to photoshop and trying to convert this image into vector path and then get its co-ordinates.

[image]

After I get the co-ordinates i will use it to develop an interactive object for a web application.

Comment: if this is not a vector already you can't automatically convert it using Photoshop, you'll have to use Illustrator.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply copy the path to Illustrator and export as SVG. The coordinates are in somewhat human readable format inside the SVG file, just open it in a text editor.

Of course, the path is a Bezier curve so "*point*" data may not be in a form that you expected. You can pre-process the path in illustrator to be a polygon by running add anchor points a few times and then simplify to straight segments. This way the list in the SVG is actually points on path.

You can also pull out point info by script, no big deal there. Its just that your use case is a bit opaque so i'm not going to go into this since i wouldnt know what the script should do.